# How to generate an Axis2 WS Client from a WSDL using Maven ?

Tags: web-services, maven, wsdl, webclient, apache-axis

I want to use Maven to generate a client for my WSDL but I have no idea how to use it.
I searched in the Internet and I couldn't find a simple tutorial that explain step by step how to configure Maven to generate the stubs and how to use those stubs to invoke the services.
Can you give me please some hints about how to use it or a tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here's a complete reference](https://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/tools/maven-plugins/axis2-wsdl2code-maven-plugin/usage.html) explaining how to generate a client/server code from a given WSDL using Maven and Axis2. Plugin execution is by default bind to `generate-sources` phase.

Comment: Thank you but this is not a tutorial, I saw this page, it explains how to configure the wsdl2java plugin ! it isn't very helpful for a newbie like me what I need is a tutorial that explain every step

Comment: which part of this tutorial makes a particular difficulty?

Comment: Hi Sergey, it's not a matter of difficulty but what I want is a complete tutorial step by step, this tutorial explain the stub generation but doesn't describe how to use it specially with Maven.

Comment: @Tanboula could you post your WSDL then I probably could help you with a more detailed explanation?